# LibGMP not found when installing CVC4 on FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, configure, gmp, abi, cvc4

I am trying to compile [CVC4](http://cvc4.cs.nyu.edu/downloads/) from source on FreeBSD, but I'm running into a hiccup at configuration time - GMP cannot be found, even though the shared object is clearly in a common path:

```
$> ls /usr/local/lib | grep gmp
libgmp.a
libgmp.la
libgmp.so
libgmp.so.10
libgmp.so.10.1.3
libgmpxx.a
libgmpxx.la
libgmpxx.so
libgmpxx.so.4
libgmpxx.so.4.3.3

$> echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/sbin: \
/usr/local/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/lib
```

...and here is the output of `./configure`:

```
...
checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp... no
configure: error: GNU MP (libgmp) not found, see http://gmplib.org/
```

After that, I did a bit of googling and found [an article describing an ABI error that I thought could be related](http://www.mpfr.org/faq.html#no_libgmp). I then compiled GMP from source, but still with no luck being found from the configure script.

What might be causing this error? Any creative ideas or help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: PATH is irrelevant. How about looking at config.log to see how exactly that test failed? Also, is your freebsd configured to look for libraries in /usr/local/lib at runtime? Was GMP installed by yourself or by freebsd's package manager?

Comment: Try "./configure LDFLAGS='-L/usr/local/lib/' <otherargs>". If that works, then Marc is likely right and either "/usr/local/lib/" or libgmp.a is not being properly found by ld. If that wasn't it, you should probably give your full "./configure" command and "builds/config.log" file. (The config.log file may also be in a directory like "builds/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/debug/config.log" i.e. architecture and configuration name). You may also email cvc-bugs@cs.nyu.edu and I or another CVC4 developer can ask more in-depth questions.

Comment: You guys are my heroes. Anyway, manually adding /usr/local/lib did not work, so here are my [configure](https://github.com/athanclark/freebsd-cvc4/blob/master/configure) and [config.log](https://github.com/athanclark/freebsd-cvc4/blob/master/config.log) files. Thank you so much, you guys are life savers. The configure file is almost a megabyte, so I really suggest you just clone the repo at `https://github.com/athanclark/freebsd-cvc4`. Thank you!!!

Comment: `configure:16729: checking for __gmpz_init in -lgmp [...] yes` that's not the same error... Now you are missing gmpxx, which you can likely get somehow through freebsd, or by compiling GMP yourself with --enable-cxx passed to configure.

Answer (score 0):

While `cvc4` isn't in the FreeBSD ports tree, `cvc3` is. Looking at that port's [Makefile](http://svnweb.freebsd.org/ports/head/math/cvc3/Makefile?revision=362025&view=markup), you need to call `configure` with some arguments. I would suggest you try that with `cvc4` as well.